# multiple PDO insert with single statement not working

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to loop through $vars_array['selected_ids'] array and insert the selected_id and page_id. It is inserting 3 records (as expected), but each record is getting a selected_id of 7.. i.e. the last selected value inserted.

```
$vars_array=array();
$vars_array['page_id']=10;
$vars_array['selected_ids']=array(2,3,7);

$sql = "INSERT INTO template_values ( page_id, selected_id) VALUES";
$sqlPart = array_fill(0, count($vars_array['selected']), "(?, ?)");
$sql .=  implode(",",$sqlPart);
$stmt=$this->database->prepare($sql);

$i = 1;
foreach($vars_array['selected_ids'] as $selected_id) {
    $stmt -> bindParam($i++, $vars_array['page_id']);
    $stmt -> bindParam($i++, $selected_id);
}
$stmt -> execute();
```

Any ideas? regards J

Comment: What does the final query look like before it's prepared? Also why not use `bindParam` with an array instead of looping over and binding individually?

Comment: Depending on the number of rows to be inserted (in this case 3): $sql = "INSERT INTO template_values ( page_id, selected_id) VALUES (?, ?),(?, ?),(?, ?)";

Comment: That looks correct. You can pass an array straight into `execute`, too, which is probably easier than firing off a potentially incorrect number of `bindParam` calls. Compose an array of values for the bindings, where the number of placeholders should match the number of things in that array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because you're using `bindParam`, and not `bindValue`. `bindParam` stores a reference to the variable you're binding, and uses the value of the variable at time of execution. That value is the same as the last iteration in your `foreach`.

Either use `bindValue` (which you usually should do anyway, since you're expecting it to use the value and not a reference - leading to subtle bugs like this) or send in an array to `execute` directly (which I usually prefer when generating a large placeholder query, since I prefer named placeholders when using bindValue).

Answer (score 0):

Alternate method:

```
    $i = 0;
    $new_array=array();
    foreach($vars_array['selected_ids'] as $selected_id) {
        $new_array[$i++]= $vars_array['page_id'];
        $new_array[$i++]= $selected_id;     
    }
    $stmt -> execute($new_array);
```

Comment: Instead of $i++, just use [] to append to the array. Removes the counter and possible bugs. :-)